# Regular expression over where clause?

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I'm trying to match specific terms on a XML file and save the results. Here is the XML text on a string:

```xml
<node1>
  <node2>
    <text>Goodbye</text>
  </node2>
  <node2>
    <text>Welcome James</text>
  </node2>
  <node2>
    <text>Welcome John</text>
  </node2>
  <node2>
    <text>See you later!</text>
  </node2>
</node1>
```

I want to use linq to select any text that has welcome in it. However the name after welcome (ex. welcome James) can change. Thus, i'm trying to understand is there an easy way to select the nodes with any welcome name in it via regular expressions?

Here's the C# code:

```
private static void Test(string stream)
{
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(stream); //stream contains the xml written above
  var list = from hello in doc.Descendants("node2")
             where attacker.Element("text").Value == "Welcome .*"
             select attacker.Element("text").Value;

  foreach (var x in attackList)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you have to use `Regex` for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a scenario as simple as yours there is no need to use regular expressions. You can use the [String.StartsWith(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx) method that determines whether a string starts with a specified string as follows:

```
private static void Test(string stream)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(stream);
    var list = from hello in doc.Descendants("node2")
               where attacker.Element("text").Value.StartsWith("Welcome")
               select attacker.Element("text").Value;

    foreach (var x in attackList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: was about to suggest `Contains`, but `StartsWith` is a better fit for this scenario.

Comment: I would change: `where attacker.Element("text").Value.ToLower().StartsWith("welcome")` ...that way you will minimize the possibility of differing cases breaking the logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("Welcome");

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(stream); //stream contains the xml written above
var list = from hello in doc.Descendants("node2")
            where regex.IsMatch(attacker.Element("text").Value)
            select attacker.Element("text").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get Regex matching is to use the static [`Regex.IsMatch(String, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx) function

If you want better performance, you can compile the regex beforehand (see [proxon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233372/regular-expression-over-where-clause/6233410#6233410)).

As [Marius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233372/regular-expression-over-where-clause/6233399#6233399) mentions though, String.StartsWith is good enough for your specific example.